# Least squares solution gives suboptimal Frobenius norm in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, linear-regression, numerical-methods

I have the following objective: || Y - A*X ||_F^2/2, where the subscript '_F' stands for the Frobenius norm.

I calculate the least-squares solution with `Y*pinv(X)` in MATLAB and compare it to another matrix `A_2` (does not matter how I calculate it).

Theoretically, it is impossible to get a solution better than the least-squares one. However, the least-squares error I get using `A = Y*pinv(X)` is around 13 and the error using `A = A_2` is around 7!

I wonder if anyone has experienced similar issues or has any idea how to resolve it.

Comment: Hi @Giorgos. Your approach seems valid so far. You probably need to check how you computed `A_2`. Could  you share this with us?

Comment: Hi @Marouen, thank you for the speedy reply. It should not matter how I calculate A_2. It is the solution of a gradient descent algorithm, but we can assume it is a randomly generated matrix. Theoretically, there should not be a better solution than the least-squares one. I tried these calculations in Python and the problem is the same there, too.

Comment: yes it makes sense, you shouldn't find a solution better than this one. Could you share the code please with A,  and Y and A_2 ?

Comment: I don't understand what the Frobenius norm has to do with all. Please share some code so that we (I^^) can better follow. Of what size is `X`? Why do you use `pinv`? Do you get the same result with `Y\X`?

Comment: @max It should be `Y/X`, as the matrix in the "denominator" is `X`. And it should indeed result in the same least-square solution `A=Y*X^T*(X*X^T)^(-1)`.

Comment: Are you sure your concluding error calculations are done with the Frobenius norm and not some different norm like the spectral one? Perhaps compute it separately using the trace formula for that norm, ||M||_F^2=trace(M*M^T) or just the square sum over all matrix elements?

Comment: Another possible source for a deviation from the expected behavior is if `X` does not have a full rank so that `X*pinv(X)` is a projector but not the identity matrix. Then indeed the formula `Y*pinv(X)` does not need to be the least-squares minimum.

Comment: @Marouen The code I use in MATLAB is the following:
`ls_norm = norm(Y - (Y*pinv(X) * X, 'fro')^2/2
 ran_norm = norm(Y - A_2 * X, 'fro')^2/2 `

Comment: @LutzLehmann The error is identical when I use Y*pinv(X) or Y/X. It is also identical to using A= Y*X^T * (X*X^T)^(-1). I have calculated the norm both using the trace and the square sum of all the elements and I again get an identical error. 

You are right about X not having full rank. X*pinv(X) is not very close to the identity. Do you know of a way to circumvent that?